# URL depending redirection htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect depending of URL which user enter, if user enter ins-dev.com to be redirected to the exact one, if enter www.ins-dev.com to remove www and redirect to ins-dev.com (http://).
But then if user enter ins-staging.com to redirect on https://ins-staging.com, in case of www to remove it and do the same redirection.
And finally if user enter trac-staging.com I would like to redirect him to https://ins-staging.com, same logic for www as above.
This is what I have for now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^ins-dev.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://ins-dev.com [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^trac-staging\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://ins-staging.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Fighting with this long time now, thanks in advance on any kind of help.
Last `%{REQUEST_URI}` is in purpose if user enter for example: ins-staging.com/video.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.((?:trac-staging|ins-staging)\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, I tried this and I'm redirect to localhost in all but one case which is `https://ins-staging.com`